# React js Route component is causing my page to become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
    const Header = () => {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div> 
                    <ul id='navBar'>
                        <li className="listElem"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                        <li className="listElem" ><Link to='/browse'>Browse</Link></li>
                        <li className="listElem" ><Link to='/cart'>Cart</Link></li>
                        <li className="listElem" ><Link to="/account_settings">Account Settings</Link></li>
                        <li className="listElem" ><Link to="/signin">Sign in</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/">
                            <Home />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/browse">
                            <BrowseInventory />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/cart">
                            <Cart />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/account_settings" >
                            <CreateAccount />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/signin">
                            <Login />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                    {/* //Currently does not work */}
                </div>
             </Router>
        )



}
```

I am not sure why, but when I use the `Route` component from react-router-dom my page never loads as in nothing appears on the screen & no components are mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to include the keyword `exact` on all your Routes

so like this

```
<Route exact path="/signin">
```

Oh yeah and another thing
I think your routes have to be at the App component instead of header
like this

```
function App(props) { <-----------------my routes are at the top level
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar /> <--------notice i have a navbar component here
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} /> <---------------see how i have exact path here
        <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route exact path="/animal/:id" component={(props) => <Showpage {...props}/>} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You see how I have my routes in the App component